# Movie Reviews Dataset

Tags: video, nlp, dataset, sentiment-analysis

I'm about to start a study on sentiment analysis and NLP and going to use movie reviews to do it. I searched the web for datasets and I found quite a few but none exactly like I need, most of them only have a bunch a movie details and tags. I want only the text reviews from critics or users and the movie title or id, like the ones you find on IMDb or Rotten Tomatoes. Is there anything like it on the web or any API or library of any language that can help me that? Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

There are many datasets of movie reviews, publicly available:

Dataset for binary sentiment classification:
http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/

Amazon movie reviews: https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Movies.html

Classify the sentiment of sentences from the Rotten Tomatoes dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/sentiment-analysis-on-movie-reviews

Collections of movie-review documents labeled with respect to their overall sentiment polarity, subjective rating (e.g., "two and a half stars") and sentences labeled with respect to their subjectivity status (subjective or objective) or polarity: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [The Movie Database API](https://developers.themoviedb.org/4/getting-started)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dataset I scraped: [480,000 Labeled Critic Reviews from Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/b4yy6p/480000_rotten_tomato_critic_reviews/). It contains critic reviews, and their rating (rotten or fresh).